# How to get an class reference in Python without calling __init__

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, object

I want to be able to dynamically specify a class reference from a dynamically specified module and pass that class reference to a third party library which then uses it. But I don't want to call the class itself (and thus the `__init__` method in the class) when I do so, that's for the library to do.

I currently have this:

```
import importlib
import thirdpartylib

# Load the module
the_module = importlib.import_module('my_module')

# Now the class
the_class = getattr(the_module, 'MyClass')()

thirdpartylib.process(the_class)
```

But of course, `getattr()` runs the `__init__` method, which I don't want.

How do I pass a reference to a class without creating an instance and triggering `__init__`?

Comment: Instance is being returned because of `()`, not `getattr`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary - Thanks; that's it; an oversight on my part; I missed those. Post it as an answer if you want and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
the_class = getattr(the_module, 'MyClass')
```

This would be the class.

> ```
> the_class = getattr(the_module, 'MyClass')()
> ```

This is an instance of the class. You have to remove the trailing `()`.